# In-memory HSQLDB issue with REQUIRES_NEW propagation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, hsqldb

I am working in a Spring Boot project, it is not very old, but should be considered to be a bit legacy. For some reason, someone decided to use in-memory HSQL db in tests, unfortunately in 1.X version. I am trying to upgrade it to the latest version 2.X.

After upgrading a dependency, a lot of tests stopped working. There are a few crucial changes between versions 1.X and 2.X, i.e.: read uncommitted was a default isolation level in old version, transaction model is different now (I use MVCC).

I found an interesting case in the application. Let's assume I have two tables: `Second` with some columns and `First` with `id, second_id` and other columns. `second_id` is a foreign key. Now, I start a test and there is an SQL script that inserts two rows:

- `Second` table: a row with `id=1`,
- `First` table: a row with `id=1`, `second_id=null`.

The script ends with `COMMIT` instruction, so these rows are committed. So, after the execution of the script, we have two rows which are not linked together by a foreign key.

Now, inside the application, new transaction starts (through `@Transactional`, propagation=`REQUIRED`). The transaction attempts to run update query on a row with `id=1` from `Second` table (`UPDATE Second SET ... WHERE id=1`). Transaction is ongoing, not committed yet.

The code hits another `@Transactional` method, however with `propagation=REQUIRES_NEW`. Current transaction is **suspended** and a new one is spawned. Inside it, the following query is executed: `update First set second_id=1 where id=1` - so basically we want to link both rows together through a foreign key. However, it fails with `foreign key no parent`.

What happens here: row which we are trying to link is currently being modified by the first transaction and it is not visible to that new transaction. And it fails. It seems to be expected according to HSQLDB transaction model, which is a bit strange comparing with other relational dbs.

Do you have any idea how to make it working without modifying the existing code? I can only touch tests and their configuration. The code has been working fine for years (yeah, the design is not nice, I know) and I am not allowed to change anything related to transaction at the moment. There are a lot of new transactions started with `REQUIRES_NEW` propagation, even in some simple cases, what is an overkill according to me.

I would be very grateful for any ideas how to proceed with that.

Comment: Configure HSQLDEB as it was behaving with 1.x (I'm assuming you are mentioning that in upgrade and not Spring Boot). Although I think the code is flawed and that is what should be fixed and not so much the tests. But apparently everything has been written with the `read_uncommitted` level in mind.

Comment: I am afraid `read_uncommitted` is no longer in version 2.X. I mean it works as `read_committed`. Also, the rows are committed before, only update part is not, so looks like it is more like HSQLDB 'feature' than standard behavior.

Comment: The update part is the problem as it is a new transaction (depending on the row is locked or not) will be overwritten by the pending one. I'm not familiar with HSQLDB that much (It has been years since I used it) so it could throw an error somewhere. I would still say the code is wrong and depended on quircky behavior of the db much more then it should.

Comment: I switched to H2 and the case I described here started to work out of the box. However, I still have a problem with camel routes. When there is a JPA endpoint and a new entity is persisted, it is not visible in next processor on the route...

Comment: Regarding camel - setting shared entity manager helped there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with HSQLDB was fixed recently. See below:

https://sourceforge.net/p/hsqldb/bugs/1684/

You can build the jar from the SVN snapshot and use it for tests.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I switched to H2 for now, I will do some testing and wait for 2.7.3 version. I will replace it back then assuming everything works as expected.